# OroCrm using FOSRestBundle $this->getManager()->createEntity()

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle, orocrm

I want to create a post API , and i have a problem when the RestController do this line :

**$entity = $this->getManager()->createEntity();**

It's return Null so the process to valid the $form bug and i have a error 500.
Whereas i create a new entity directly in the **public function handleCreateRequest()**
it's work well , my entity is created and put in my database.
So why the createEntity() return null knowing that this method is in ApiEntityManager.php et return **new $this->class**

this is my Controller Post Method :

```
 /**
* REST POST Product
*
* @ApiDoc(
*      section="Product",
*      description="Post product item",
*      resource=true
* )
* @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
*/
public function postAction()
{

  return $this->handleCreateRequest();
}
```

And this is the **handleCreateRequest()**

```
/**
 * Create new
 *
 * @return Response
 */
 public function handleCreateRequest()
 {
      $entity = $this->getManager()->createEntity(); <---- this line return null
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
//    $entity = new \GroupeGC\Bundle\ProductBundle\Entity\Product();    |
//    $entity->setCode( $this->getRequest()->get("code"));              |
//    $entity->setLabel( $this->getRequest()->get("label"));            |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
//this part of code work well but it's not generic


    $isProcessed = $this->processForm($entity);

    if ($isProcessed) {
        $entityClass = ClassUtils::getRealClass($entity);
        $classMetadata = $this->getManager()->getObjectManager()->getClassMetadata($entityClass);
        $view = $this->view($classMetadata->getIdentifierValues($entity), Codes::HTTP_CREATED);
    } else {
        $view = $this->view($this->getForm(), Codes::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    return $this->handleView($view);
}
```

EDIT 1 :

if i do a var_dump() of $entity : the result is : 
**string 'GroupeGC\Bundle\ProductBundle\Entity\Product' (length=44)** (so it's not null) 
So why it's doesn't work 0_o

Comment: Is your getManager method calling the right service?

Answer (score 1):

Did you implement

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getManager()
{
    return $this->get('your_manager_service_name');
}
```

In your controller?

And your_manager_service_name should be declared in services.yml something like that:

```
    your_manager_service_name:
    class: %your_manager_service_name.class%
    arguments:
        - %your.entity.class%
        - @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
```